# Android unable to use for-loop to get user data from Parse.com database

Tags: android, android-listview, parse-platform

I am looking to get the names of a few users from the parse.com DB based on a few queries, for which I am using a for loop to get users and load it into a listview using a custom adapter and the code I have used is as under :

```
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseUser> pusers, ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (e==null) {
            for (ParseUser pu : pusers) {
                Users1[] data = new Users1[] {
                    new Users1(pu.getString("Name"), true)
                };
            }
            UserListAdapter mUserAdapter = new UserListAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.user_list_item, data);                        
        } else {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ManualInviteActivity.this);
            builder.setMessage(R.string.login_error_message);
            builder.setTitle(R.string.login_error_title);
            builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    }
});
```

I am getting an error when I try to initialize the adapter at 'data' which says that data cannot be resolved to a variable, when I have created it already. How do I fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of below code:

```
                       if(e==null)
                        {
                            for(ParseUser pu : pusers)
                            {
                                Users1[] data = new Users1[]
                                        {
                                        new Users1(pu.getString("Name"), true)
                                        };
                            }
                            UserListAdapter mUserAdapter = new UserListAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.user_list_item, data);

                        }
```

Use this corrected code:

```
                         if(e==null)
                            {
                            Users1[] data = null;
                            int i=0;  

                            for(ParseUser pu : pusers)
                            {

                                  if(data==null){
                                     data = new Users1[pusers.size()];
                                   }                                            

                                   Users1 user=new Users1(pu.getString("Name"), true);
                                   data[i]= user;
                                   i++;     
                            }
                            UserListAdapter mUserAdapter = new UserListAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.user_list_item, data);

                        }
```

Answer (score 2):

What are you doing wrong is, initialising the array each time it enters the loop, i.e.

```
for(ParseUser pu : pusers)
{
   Users1[] data = new Users1[]
   {
         new Users1(pu.getString("Name"), true) // here every time new instance is created.
   }
}
```

So instead of this, initialise it outside the for loop -

```
Users1[] data = new Users1 [pusers.size()];
```

then start your for loop

```
int i = 0;
for(ParseUser pu : pusers)
{
   Users1 user=new Users1(pu.getString("Name"), true);
   data[i]= user;
   i++;     
}
UserListAdapter mUserAdapter = new UserListAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.user_list_item, data);
```